# Brew could not link jpeg

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, homebrew

I'm getting this error when I tried to install PIL on my osx lion -

*"You must `brew link jpeg' before pil can be installed"*

So I followed that instruction, but got another error instead -

*"Linking /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d... Warning: Could not link jpeg. Unlinking...
Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d/bin/wrjpgcom
Target /usr/local/bin/wrjpgcom already exists. You may need to delete it.
To force the link and delete this file, do:"*

I found a post in the site - https://superuser.com/questions/402032/brew-link-jpeg-issues - but doesn't solve my problem. Can anyone tell me how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

From your own link, I learned to try

```
brew cleanup
```

then I could just link as needed.

Answer (score 2):

I went into the exactly same problem as you, it takes me one hour to solve it.
try

```
brew link jpeg
```

it will give you some hint, like

```
"Linking /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d... Warning: Could not link jpeg. Unlinking... Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d/bin/wrjpgcom Target /usr/local/bin/wrjpgcom already exists. You may need to delete it. To force the link and delete this file, do:"
```

you need to delete it.
the uncleaned files...

after several deleting work done,you will find that the uncleaned files are stored in

```
/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d/bin/
```

just delete all the files under the dir.

```
rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d/bin/*
```

then, your environment is basicly clean.
  try

```
brew install PIL
```

it should work.but it's not finished. you will find that after the installation, some error message come up: the link to PIL comes into some problem. unlinking... 
   try

```
brew link PIL
```

if it works, all is done. your PIL is well installed.
   but if you use a virtual environment, you may like to create a soft link to your venv.

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/pil/1.1.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL  /Users/nan/social_master/socialvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL
```

hope it's helpful!

Comment: @andrew the 'jpeg' and 'pil' has some strong dependence, while you remove 'pil','jpeg' can't be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Got this from stack overflow site itself..

Make sure you have homebrew and pip, and then run:

```
brew install libjpeg 
pip install pil
```

And i forgot to mention that if above commands doesn't do the trick, do this

> Make sure that you are NOT using GCC 4.0. That means those export
>   lines in your .bash_profile file that you needed to get MySQLdb
>   working now need to go away.
>
> get (http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v7.tar.gz) and do the usual
>   ./configure && make && make install (or whatever the readme says).
>
> Before installing PIL but after installing libjpeg, change the
>   “JPEG_ROOT = None” line in my setup.py file to “JPEG_ROOT =
>   libinclude(“/usr/local”)”

Afterwards you can reinstall PIL through pip or easy_install.Make sure all the compiled stuff from your last run is deleted.

Comment: I got his error from first line - The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
You can try again using `brew link jpeg'

Comment: Force parameter resolve the issue but PIL isn't installed properly. Cuz Im getting No module found error in python. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?